# jekyll serve and launch

Tags: bash, jekyll

Being lazy, I would like to chain the following two commands so that it will work with one simple bash alias.

```
jekyll -w serve
```

starts up the development server for my jekyll instance.

```
open "http://localhost:4000"
```

launches my jekyll application in my default browser.

How can I chain them together so that I can type *one simple alias* in my command line to serve and launch?

**NOTES**

- Note using either `&&` or `;` to chain `jekyll -w serve` and `open "http://localhost:4000"` will not work because the `jekyll -w serve` launches the persistent webrick process in stdout.  Which means that the 2nd command `open "http://localhost:4000"` will not be executed because the first process (webrick) never did "complete".
- When webrick starts, we can see a typical output as follows:-

> ```
> Configuration file: /Users/calvin/work/calviny/_config.yml
>             Source: /Users/calvin/work/calviny
>        Destination: /Users/calvin/work/calviny/_site
>       Generating... done.
>  Auto-regeneration: enabled
> [2013-09-08 18:43:58] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
> [2013-09-08 18:43:58] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]
> [2013-09-08 18:43:58] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=6183 port=4000
> ```

Comment: I asked essentially the same question, and [here’s a working solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25177206/704015).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Currently I see the following options:

- use `expect` to start jekyll and later on the browser depending on a certain line of output from `jekyll` that shows that it is safe to start the browser now.
- write a small program that sequentially tries to connect to port `4000`. If a connection could be established in a given time, the browser can be started. Of course you could also use wget or curl and sequentially try to load the index.html.
- you may recognize that `jekyll` is ready based on the presence of certain files. You could code something with `inotifywait` to start the browser *after* such a file has been created. (But I don't know `jekyll`, I'm not sure if this is really an option)

Comment: This is exactly what I attempted but it won't work because in order for `open "http://localhost:4000"` to run, `jekyll -w serve` needs to be "completed" - which it is not since it is launched and waiting for further events.

Comment: you mean jekyll starts as a daemon? (I don't know the program)

Comment: jekyll development server is webrick (ruby on rails uses webrick as a development server too) and it does not move to the background. Upon launch, the results are shown on stdout as a persistent process. 

So until I terminate the webrick process with a ctrl-c, the second command `open "http://localhost:4000"` will not execute.

Comment: why not starting the browser first, in background. (You'll have reload the page once when jekyll is ready, this should be ok, ins't it?)

Comment: Not quite. I am trying to start the development server and launch my web application after the development server has started without manual intervention. I am lazy.

Comment: you can use `expect` and start the browser depending on a certain line of output from `jekyll` (something like "ready ...")  do you know `expect`?

Answer (score 12):

As of [v3.70](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/releases/tag/v3.7.0) these hacks are no longer needed. Now `jekyll serve` has LiveReload functionality and will automatically spawn the default browser with the `-o, --open-url` option. The `-l, --livereload` option will automatically rebuild and refresh the browser upon changes.

```
bundle exec jekyll serve -l -o
```

Comment: Why is it that I always have to find basic stuff like this on non-official posts from the second page of google results, and never from the official Jekyll docs.

Answer (score 1):

```
function jek {
    jekyll -w serve & open "http://localhost:4000" 
}
```

solves the problem.  A single `&`.

Comment: how will this make sure that the webserver on port 4000 is started before the browser will being spawned? It's actually the same as starting the browser before the jekyll command (what I have suggested ~hour before) using this solution you will need to refresh the browser after the web server has been started

Comment: I've added an option to my answer: poll port 4000 and start the browser if a connection can be established. you could even use wget or curl and try to load - let's say the index.html - instaed of wrinting a small program for that

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on terminal commands, but this seems to have solved it for me. Tested it a few times without issue. (I'm running osx 10.8 if it makes any difference to you)

```
function jek {
    jekyll -w serve & sleep 5 && open "http://localhost:4000"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As hek2mgl suggested, you can do this with `expect`:

```
set timeout 5
spawn jekyll serve
expect {
    -re {Server address:\s+(.+)$} {
        set address $expect_out(1,string)
    }
}
expect "Server running..."
catch {
    exec xdg-open $address
}
interact
```

Answer (score 0):

`jekyll serve > /dev/null 2>&1 & sleep 5 && open "http://localhost:4000"`