# Run process when string in STDOUT is matched

Tags: bash

I’m running my blog with [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) and I thought it’d be a nice idea to automatically open the site in a new browser tab when the local development server finishes starting up.

When you run `jekyll serve`, you have some output like the following:

```
Configuration file: /Users/jgt/Sites/jezen.github.io/_config.yml
        Source: /Users/jgt/Sites/jezen.github.io
   Destination: dist
  Generating...
                done.
Configuration file: /Users/jgt/Sites/jezen.github.io/_config.yml
    Server address: http://0.0.0.0:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

I had thought of running `jekyll serve` in a subshell and listening for its output. Maybe I could at the same time fire up a concurrent infinite loop that reads some stdout and runs `open http://0.0.0.0:4000` and then exits when the string "Server running" is matched. My bash-fu is not yet at a level where I can hack something together.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this in bash:

```
(jekyll serve) | while read line; do 
    [[ $line =~ "Server running" ]] && open http://0.0.0.0:4000
done
```

This runs `jekyll serve` in a subshell and pipes `stdout` to the loop. It then uses bash regex matching to match the line containing the words "Server running".

Comment: Excellent! Works a charm. I wrap this in `nohup` and `&` so it just magically runs in the background.

Comment: A question though (and forgive my naïvety): does the loop exit once it finds a match? Or does it keep infinitely looping? Should I care?

Comment: The `while` loop will continue until the `jekyll serve` process terminates. It's not doing much so I wouldn't worry about it :)

Comment: More specifically, the loop terminate when `read` encounters an end-of-file. As far I'm aware, when the subshell terminates, that is what will happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply redirect stdout to a file, and then tail this file, grep for your string and then trigger your action

```
run proccess > outputfile;
tail -f outputfile| grep "your string"| while read string; do open http://0.0.0.0:4000; done
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but I’m not too keen on generating files to pass data around.